# How to map filesystem path to http url in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm working on a spring web mvc  project which allows users to upload files. I am saving these uploaded files out of application context so that they persist across deployments. Saving file is working fine. I want to know the best way to convert the file system path to HTTP url so that it can be saved in the database and also used in HTML resource like  etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to move your file from the filesystem to a database field and then serve it as a resource or do you want to access a file in the filesystem like a static resource? If it's the second option, check: http://wordgraphs.com/post/1751/Serving-a-resource-from-outside-the-context-root-in-Spring-MVC

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's the second option and I did check this link. What I don't understand is in my html tag do I need to put a relative url or a fully qualified url. Also in case I decide to store these files on a different server I would need a fully qualified url. How to handle that case as well?

Comment: Also in case of I store files on the same server, should I then store the relative or fully qualified path in the DB?

Comment: In your html tag you need to use a relative url (being aware of your context, so you could access your file like http://yourhost:port/context/resource/yourfile). In case you want to store files in a different server then you should add another resource origin (but it must be available as a file system path to the other server), so in that case it would make sense to store in the database a value like "resourcename/filename". In case you store all the files in the same path in the same server using only one resource, then you could only store in the db the filename.

Comment: Yeah thank you. I got it working with the same method.

Comment: If you add it as a answer I will mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to access a file in the filesystem like a static resource using spring mvc, the answer (taken from [here](http://wordgraphs.com/post/1751/Serving-a-resource-from-outside-the-context-root-in-Spring-MVC)) is to serve the static resources adding an entry like in your servlet context:

Example:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="file:/absolute/path/to/the/resource/folder/" />
```

In this case you store all the files in the same path in the same server using only one resource, then you could only store in the db the filename.

In your html tag you need to use a relative url (being aware of your context, so you could access your file like `http://yourhost:port/context/resource/yourfile`).

In case you want to store files in a different server then you should add another resource origin (but it must be available as a file system path to the other server), so in that case it would make sense to store in the database a value like "`resourcename/filename`".

Comment: What should I do for a Spring boot project, since we don't have the xml file which can be found for a Spring mvc project?